# rdpmc in user mode does not work even with PCE set

Tags: performance, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, intel-pmu

Based on the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR4) as well as the Intel manual, `rdpmc` should be available to user-mode processes as long as `bit 8` of `CR4` is set. However, I am still running into `general protection` error when trying to run `rdpmc` from userspace even with that bit set.

I am running on an 8-core `Intel X3470` on kernel `2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64`.

Here is the user-mode program I am trying to execute:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <sched.h>
#include <assert.h>

uint64_t
read_pmc(int ecx)
{
    unsigned int a, d;
    __asm __volatile("rdpmc" : "=a"(a), "=d"(d) : "c"(ecx));
    return ((uint64_t)a) | (((uint64_t)d) << 32);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    uint64_t start, end;
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    unsigned int c;
    int i;

    if (ac != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s cpu-id pmc-num\n", av[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    i = atoi(av[1]);
    c = atoi(av[2]);
    
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(i, &cpuset);
        assert(sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset) == 0);

    printf("%lu\n", read_pmc(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the kernel module which sets the bit and reads out `CR4` so I can manually verify that the bit has been set.

```c
/*  
 *  Enable PMC in user mode.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>



int init_module(void)
{
    typedef long unsigned int uint64_t;
    uint64_t output;
    // Set CR4, Bit 8  to enable PMC
__asm__("push   %rax\n\t"
                "mov    %cr4,%rax;\n\t"
                "or     $(1 << 7),%rax;\n\t"
                "mov    %rax,%cr4;\n\t"
                "wbinvd\n\t"
                "pop    %rax"
    );

    // Read back CR4 to check the bit.
    __asm__("\t mov %%cr4,%0" : "=r"(output));
    printk(KERN_INFO "%lu", output);

    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
__asm__("push   %rax\n\t"
        "push   %rbx\n\t"
                "mov    %cr4,%rax;\n\t"
                "mov  $(1 << 7), %rbx\n\t"
                "not  %rbx\n\t"
                "and   %rbx, %rax;\n\t"
                "mov    %rax,%cr4;\n\t"
                "wbinvd\n\t"
                "pop    %rbx\n\t"
                "pop    %rax\n\t"
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Since you don't know on which cpu the kernel set `CR4` I assume you tried all in the test program?

Comment: Yes. I originally wanted my module to set CR4 on all cores, but I couldn't figure out how to set CPU affinity inside the module.

Comment: You can use `on_each_cpu` or `on_each_cpu_mask` from `smp.h`

Comment: @Jester, it looks promising, but I'm not sure how to interpret the parameter `wait` for `on_each_cpu` and the comment on top does not shed any light on it. Is `wait` supposed to be a boolean, or a timeout? If a timeout, what are its units?

Comment: It's a boolean. I am sure you could have found that yourself.

Comment: @Jester, I used `on_each_cpu` and confirmed that the instruction is actually run on each CPU but still get general protection when calling `rdpmc` in user mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, when Intel says `Bit 8`, they are referring to the **9th bit** from the right, since their indexing begins at `0`. Replacing `$(1 << 7)` with `$(1 << 8)` globally resolves the issue, and allows `rdpmc` to be called from user mode.

Here is the updated kernel module, also using `on_each_cpu` to make sure that it is set on every core.

```c
/*  
 *  Read PMC in kernel mode.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

static void printc4(void) {
    typedef long unsigned int uint64_t;
    uint64_t output;
    // Read back CR4 to check the bit.
    __asm__("\t mov %%cr4,%0" : "=r"(output));
    printk(KERN_INFO "%lu", output);
}

static void setc4b8(void * info) {
    // Set CR4, Bit 8 (9th bit from the right)  to enable
__asm__("push   %rax\n\t"
                "mov    %cr4,%rax;\n\t"
                "or     $(1 << 8),%rax;\n\t"
                "mov    %rax,%cr4;\n\t"
                "wbinvd\n\t"
                "pop    %rax"
    );

    // Check which CPU we are on:
    printk(KERN_INFO "Ran on Processor %d", smp_processor_id());
    printc4();
}

static void clearc4b8(void * info) {
    printc4();
__asm__("push   %rax\n\t"
        "push   %rbx\n\t"
                "mov    %cr4,%rax;\n\t"
                "mov  $(1 << 8), %rbx\n\t"
                "not  %rbx\n\t"
                "and   %rbx, %rax;\n\t"
                "mov    %rax,%cr4;\n\t"
                "wbinvd\n\t"
                "pop    %rbx\n\t"
                "pop    %rax\n\t"
    );
    printk(KERN_INFO "Ran on Processor %d", smp_processor_id());
}



int init_module(void)
{
    on_each_cpu(setc4b8, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    on_each_cpu(clearc4b8, NULL, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Echoing "2" to /sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu/rdpmc allows user processes
to access performance counters via the rdpmc instruction.
Note that behaviour has changed. Prior to 4.0 "1" meant "enabled"
while meant "0" disable. Now "1" means allow only for processes that have active perf events. More details: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html